# Query child records using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Here is my edmx diagram. 
[image]

I am trying to get all the drives for a particular ProfileId

Here is the query i have written

```
var prof = (from p in pe.UserDrives.Include("Drive")
                    where p.ProfileId == Cuser.ProfileId
                    select p).ToList();
```

Data:

```
Drive

Id  googleAccount   RefreshToken    AccessToken
1   Cloud            NULL            NULL
2   Storage          NULL            NULL

UserDrive
DriveId Id  ProfileId
1        1  1
2        2  1
```

The result i would get is the drive info for profileId =1 would be 2 records from userdrive and its corresponding drive information

Instead i would want to have For selected profile have a list of drive records

Kindly bear the newbiesh question. I am just learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select the `Drive` property instead of the `UserDrive`. Like this:

```
var prof = (from p in pe.UserDrives.Include("Drive")
                    where p.ProfileId == Cuser.ProfileId
                    select p.Drive).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any performace difference in using the syntax you have used and what @anurag has written in his answer. I am just learning and would like to know the best practice  . Thanks your answer worked

Comment: If anything, his will probably be a little slower since he is pulling in the Profile table as well. Were that not the case, I would say the difference would probably be negligible. As an aside, when you create your context you can add a line after like this `context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);` to see the actual query generated as well as the execution time.

Comment: I usually wrap that line in a `#if DEBUG` in order to eliminate the performance hit from logging in production.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Will try out the #if DEBUG as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Please try it

```
var prof = (from p in Profile
              join ud in UserDrive on p.id equals ud.profileId
              join d in drive on ud.driveid equals d.Id
              where p.ProfileId == Cuser.ProfileId
              select new { p,ud,d}).tolist();
string a = prof.p.columnname;
string b = prof.ud.columnname;
string c = prof.d.columnname;
```

Comment: Is there any performace difference in using the syntax you have used and what @pquest has written in his answer. I am just learning and would like to know the best practice  .